# MongoDB collections in zero with authentication

Tags: database, mongodb, authentication, collections

We currently are trying to make MongoDB 3.0 a bit more secure by adding users, roles and passwords, disabling the anonymous logins

However, when we enable auth=true or the --auth command in starting MongoDB, we can login with the DB administrator, (admins all of the DB) but we can't see any data in MongoDB Compass when the authentication is turned on, also, it shows that all of the databases have 0 Bytes of size and no Collection is shown.

Can you help me pinpoint where is the issue?

**EDIT:** Here is an Image of the things that our DB show on the Compass Community Edition, per clarification of the question [image: Image From Mongo Community]

Comment: So, you have user with `roles: [ "root" ]` and still you don't see "everything"?!?

Comment: @JJussi that is right, I have the  UserAdminAnyDatabase and I don't se everything, in fact, I see nothing, even when I create new users for a single Database with the dbAdmin role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding the Read Role to the user Database by Database, also, in the login, I have to explicitly state the Database I am going to connect to

Basically the dbAdmin does not have the read role and has to be included manually

Regards and thanks